# Vim binding in browsers

Tags: vim, browser, key-bindings

I have been googling for a way to use vim bindings inside normal text fields in chrome. I've tried vmium and cVim but I can't figure out whether they have the functionality I'm looking for.

An example is this exact text area in which I'm typing my question. I'd like to be able to press Esc and go to vim command mode in here, and start deleting a line pressing dd.

Would that be possible? Or those plugins are just for navigation shortcuts?

Comment: Those plugins are for navigation only. If you want a Vi-like experience in Chrome's textareas, try [Wasavi](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wasavi/dgogifpkoilgiofhhhodbodcfgomelhe?hl=fr).

Comment: vote for closing. but I would suggest TextAid. I am using it with chrome. It is not giving you vim-like binding in text areas, it lets you start vim/gvim to edit your text. For example the answer and comment at SO. For me the TextAid is a must have chromium plugin.

Comment: Wasavi is what I wanted, thanks @romainl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer!

> Those plugins are for navigation only. If you want a Vi-like
>   experience in Chrome's textareas, try Wasavi. –  @romainl

Answer (score 0):

The cVim plugin allows for keyboard shortcuts to manipulate text inside text boxes. However, the shortcuts are not the same as vim and there are not as many. After installing the extension type ":help" to see the list of shortcuts.